# How to fix #1227 - Access denied error and delete row from database on expiry

Tags: mysql

I wanted to delete the record from database after its expiry and that too automatically. I tried creating event, using PROCEDURE to schedule the event after every minute. I was also trying to put Scheduler ON, but it too gave me an error,

> #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

I wanted to know how to fix this error and how to delete records after their specific expiry date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that you don't have permission for delete operation. Go to phpmyadmin and check permissions for user that is connected to your database.

Comment: may i know where i will get those permissions. I am using Hostgator phpmyadmin.

Comment: I'm not sure which version of phpmyadmin is installed on that hosting but you can see in official documentation how to edit existing user and change permissions. http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/privileges.html

Comment: Server type: Percona Server
Server version: 5.5.42-37.1 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 37.1, Revision 727

Comment: These are my Server details. I am the only user still i cannot put on the event schedular.

Comment: i am having all the privileges access to my database still i cannot use event scheduler.